# How t have the RDLC pie chart show ranges instead of individual values

Tags: rdlc

I have some data coming from a custom dataset that look like the following example

Person Age

P1      20

P2      21

P3      30

P4      31

P5      40

And I want to develop a pie showing the age distribution against the age.

The point is that I want this Age to be shown in ranges. (20-29, 30-39, etc for example
So we have:
Slice with total number =2 (P1 + P2) as age is 20-29 (one at 20 and another at 21)

Slice with total number =3 (P3 + P4) as age is 30-39 (one at 30 and another at 31)

Slice with total number =1 (P5) as age is 40 (one at 40).

How can i customize the pie chart to aggregate values by ranges that I can define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click Chart -> Data -> Category Groups,
Change the Data values Group on expression and the Labels to something like

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Age.Value < 25, "Under 25", 
    ((Fields!Age.Value >=25) AND (Fields!Age.Value < 35)), "26 - 35", 
    ((Fields!Age.Value >=35) AND (Fields!Age.Value < 45)), "36 - 45", 
    ((Fields!Age.Value >=45) AND (Fields!Age.Value < 55)), "46 - 55", 
    ((Fields!Age.Value >=55) AND (Fields!Age.Value < 65)), "56 - 65", 
    Fields!Age.Value > 65, "Over 65"
    )
```